# Replace values in column based on corresponding values in other row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
col1    col2
a     10       
a     NaN        
a     NaN        
b     19          
b     NaN      
b     NaN 

col1    col2
a     10       
a     10        
a     10       
b     19          
b     19      
b     19
```

I basically have a dataset (with more columns but just included these for simplicity) where only one row has the value in `col2` that responds to the value in `col1` and I need all of the null values to be replaced with the corresponding value.

Keep in mind this is a large data set with thousands of different values for `col1`.

I tried changing the index and using `.apply()`

Comment: try .mask() to replace values. Do a boolean mask and then apply the replace flag with the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby`:

```
>>> df["col2"] = df.groupby("col1")["col2"].transform("first")
```

Comment: Might not be immediately obvious to some some newer coders why this is a safter choice than ffill, but could be worth mentioning

Comment: @Chris `Series.ffill()` or `GroupBy.ffill`? I can see why you wouldn't want to use the `Series` one but the `GroupBy` one seems fine.

Comment: `GroupBy` one wouldn't be fine either if the valid value was 2nd or 3rd within a group. OP only mentioned "one" value, but it's not necessarily the first row in each group.